# Remove all HTML between two points

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, web

I would like to know how to remove all the HTML between two strings in a webpage. The webpage will not always have the same content, so this must work no matter what the two strings are and what their positions are. For example,

```
<div class='foo'>
   <div class='userid'>123</div>
   <div class='content'>
      asdfasdf
   </div>
</div>
<div class=bar>
   <div class='userid'>456</div>
   <div class='content'>
      qwerqwer
   </div>
</div>
```

How could I remove all the HTML between 'asdfasdf' and '123'?

Thanks

Comment: Using Javascript? That isn't going to be completely easy. What exactly do you want to do, can you elaborate?

Comment: "no matter what the two strings are and what their positions are" - how do you identify what and where they are then? And what do you want to end up with?

Comment: Do you mean remove anything that is within the 'content' divs?

Comment: Does not make sense to me. I'm sure there is a much better solution to your problem than doing this, whatever the problem might be. What are you trying to solve here?

Comment: Is it ok to hide something? Or do you really want to delete it?

Comment: To be clear, it might be helpful to mention whether "between" is inclusive. I'm also interested in knowing why you need to do this, if it's possible for you to provide any details. There may be another way to get what you want with DOM manipulation rather than string manipulation with the markup.

Comment: Indeed what are you trying to do? removing the content between divs, or completly deleting the html ? Or just hiding it?

Comment: @bažmegakapa I think he is trying to TRIM the DOM nodes.

Comment: Hiding is fine, I'd just like to be able to hide everything between those two divs and including those two divs, sorry for not explaining correctly.

Comment: To result with DOM like this
<div class='userid'>123asdfasdf</div>?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is ugly but it works:

```
​var container = $("#cont");
var text = container.html();
var arr = text.split("asdfasdf");
arr[1] = "";
arr = arr.join("");
$("#cont").html(arr);
```

I added a container div.  You could use the body tag or something else.  Its possible with a regex as well.

Here is a working demo http://jsfiddle.net/QJSJH/.

**Edit**

I see the post changed quite a bit, but you could use the same concept as above.